# Как заполнять список только уникальными значениями

Tags: kotlin, list, коллекции

Подскажите как заполнять а может только возвращать из списка уникальные числа
Нужно сделать так, чтобы в консоль выводилось три ряда с пятью столбцами из уникальных чисел на всех трех рядах.

```
fun card() = MutableList(3){
            MutableList(5){
                Random.nextInt(1,MAX)
            }
        }

val artur = card()

artur.forEach { row ->
      println(row)
    }
```

Comment: Как инициализировать не подскажу, а возвращать: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения задачи можете использовать [generateSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) и [distinct](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html).

Вот пример кода:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

const val MAX = 20 // Максимальное значение для случайных чисел


fun generateUniqueNumbers(amount: Int, max: Int): List<Int> {
    return generateSequence { Random.nextInt(1, max) }
        .distinct()
        .take(amount)
        .toList()
}

fun card(): List<List<Int>> {
    return List(3) {
        generateUniqueNumbers(5, MAX)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val artur = card()

    artur.forEach { row ->
        println(row)
    }
}
```

Функция `card()` создает "карту" размером 3x5

`generateUniqueNumbers` создает список уникальных чисел заданного количества из диапазона от 1 до *MAX* (Константа которую мы указали в самом начале, равная **20**)

Пример выполнения программы:

```
[16, 8, 12, 7, 13]
[3, 16, 11, 6, 5]
[16, 9, 10, 3, 1]
```

Comment: А где тут уникальность чисел, число 16 три раза повторяется

Comment: @user551312 А вы написали разве про уникальность на каждом ряду или уникальные на все 3 ряда? А вы описали, что должно происходить при кейсе, в котором MAX < 15? Нет. Пишите следующий раз полное условие.