# Как заполнять все три ряда в списке неповторяющимися значениями

Tags: kotlin, list, коллекции

Подскажите как возвращать из списка уникальные числа

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в консоль выводилось три ряда с пятью столбцами из уникальных чисел на всех трех рядах. То есть, чтобы числа в рядах не совпадали друг с другом

```
fun card() = MutableList(3){
            MutableList(5){
                Random.nextInt(1,MAX)
            }
        }

val artur = card()

artur.forEach { row ->
      println(row)
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заполнять список только уникальными значениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1557925/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз